# how to reduce complexity of API's Url

Tags: angularjs, api, url

I have four API's which use in different different controllers.

Url: "htp://192.168.0.**31**:8010/register"

Url: "htp://192.168.0.**31**:8010/login"

Url: "htp://192.168.0.**31**:8010/verifyAccount"

Url: "htp://192.168.0.**31**:8010/profile"

and a Global URL

Url: "htp://192.168.0.**31**:8010/

I want to know when Global URL change **31 to 16**
like

Url: "htp://192.168.0.**16**:8010/

Then I have to change all API's url **31 to 16**.This is so complex and time taken .

How can I Overcome it ? 
please give me suggestion.

Comment: Use DNS to assign a name to that IP address. When the IP address of the server changes, also change the DNS. So your application always use the same name. In the JS code, in general, don't hard-code the same value everywhere. Hardcode it once, in a constant, and use that constant everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using  `Constant` in your angular `app.js`

Example :

```
 app.constant("apiurl", {

        url:"htp://192.168.0.31:8010",

    });
```

Inject this Constant as a Dependency to ur controller and access the apiurl as follows:

```
Url : apiurl.url + 'register';
```

Comment: I used   app.constant("apiurl", "htp://192.168.0.31:8010",); and its work Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve with [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

1. add `API_URL` in **.value** provider

   ```
    angular
       .module('app')
       .config(routerConfig)
       .value('API_URL', 'http://192.168.0.31:8010');
   ```
2. use `API_URL` in http interceptor

   ```
    angular
       .module('app')
       .factory('httpInterceptor', function($q, API_URL) {
           var refresh = false;
           var interceptor = {
               request: function(config) {
                   // console.log('before config.url', config.url);
                   var url = config.url;
                   // skip the interceptor for any html request
                   if (url.substr(url.length - 5) == '.html') {
                       return config || $q.when(config);
                   }
                   config.url = API_URL + url;
               }               
           };
           return interceptor;
    });
   ```
3. Now in your other service where you are using $http, you can directly call the api method ; it will go through interceptor which will add `API_URL`

   ```
   angular
   .module('app')
   .factory('AuthService', function($http) {

       var service = {

           login: function(credentials) {
               return $http.post('/login');
           },

           logout: function() {
               return $http.get('/logout');
           }
      }; 
      return service;
   });
   ```